# Drupal Taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I need to create nested taxonomy. (for drill down kinda search)

Example: I have a vocabulary:
Cars
-Mercedes
--SLK
--CLK
-BMW
--7 series
--3 series
-Aston Martin
--DB9
--DB7

What I want to do is to have 3 lists, so users could first select Make, then model, and then show all created content for the select. 
Is there any good plugin for use with taxonomy? 
I tried to use: http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select but it lacks documentation.
Also, I've seen Taxonomy VTN, but not sure whether it is something I need to use.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hierarchical select` is a good module, combine it with `Views` to get the behaviour you're after. You will need to add an exposed filter to your view for the taxonomy term, and make sure the `Hierarchical Select Taxonomy Views` module is enabled.